# Canonical map is injective

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, flatness

Let $A$ and $B$ be commutative rings, and let $f:A\to B$ be a faithfully flat ring homomorphism. How can I show that for any $A$-module $M$, the canonical map $M\to M\otimes_AB$ is injective?

I was wondering that do we need the assumption that $f$ is faithfully flat as the part (c) of the problem does not use the mapping $f$ so is the assumption only for other parts of the problem?

(Liu, *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*, Exercise 1.2.19(c).)

Comment: I don't understand very well what you are asking, but if you think the above map is injective without the faithfully flatness of $A\to B$, then you are wrong: even for flat maps like $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Q$ this fails as shows $M=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $K=\ker(M\to M\otimes_AB)$. Then $K=\{x\in M:x\otimes 1=0\}$. We show that $K\otimes_AB=0$: $x\otimes b=(x\otimes 1)b=0$, so $K=0$.